# Renewing the user's access token and posting while the user is offline

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0, server-side

I have a Facebook app that handles most interactions with Facebook on the client side, however, I need to eventually post to the user's wall while the user is offline. I am currently storing the user's id and access token but I'm lost on how to renew the access token.

I assume it would be just a question of calling a graph method passing my app is, secret and the user id to get a new access token since the user has previously given the app all the necessary permissions but I can't seem to find anything like this on the docs. Am I taking the correct approach here or is there something else I should do in order to post as the offline user?

Thank you

Comment: I'm not familiar with the facebook API, but you should store a refresh token instead of an access token. An access token expires and cannot be renewed, the refresh token is used to query a new access token instead. See the OAuth 2 specification for a sample token refresh request/response message.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has removed the concept of an offline user for third party applications, if the user isn't actively using your application then it is reasonable for the token to expire. You can extend the short lived token to two months. See https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/